# How can I refactor this query

Tags: sql, oracle, refactoring

How can I rewrite this SQL code? I would like to avoid the repetitive execution of the case for every record.

```
SELECT chcr.chsid,
CASE
WHEN EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM hdr_run chre,
    clmerr ce
  WHERE chre.chsid       = chcr.chsid
  AND chre.run_nmbr      < chcr.last_run_nmbr
  AND chre.clm_error_sid = ce.clm_error_sid
  GROUP BY chre.chsid
  HAVING COUNT(chre.clm_error_sid) > 0
  )
THEN 'Appended'
ELSE 'Never Appended'
END Run_Detail
FROM 
clm_res chcr,
clm_der chde
WHERE chde.chsid          = chcr.chsid
```

Comment: Your statement does not appear valid.  You have an `AND` but no `WHERE`.  I've modified the statement to have a `WHERE` and removed the `AND`.  If that's not what you actually have, please edit your question to fix the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at that query please:

```
SELECT 
    chcr.chsid,
    CASE
        WHEN ce.clm_error_sid IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(chre.clm_error_sid, 0) > 0
            THEN 'Appended'
            ELSE 'Never Appended'
    END Run_Detail
FROM 
    clm_res chcr
        JOIN clm_der chde ON chde.chsid = chcr.chsid
        LEFT JOIN hdr_run chre ON chre.chsid = chcr.chsid AND chre.run_nmbr < chcr.last_run_nmbr
        LEFT JOIN clmerr ce ON chre.clm_error_sid = ce.clm_error_sid
GROUP BY chcr.chsid
```

If there's more than one `clm_der` for each `clm_res` based on their `chsid`, we'd have to double check that the `COUNT` is not counting the extras from `clm_der`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no data to test this on so all I can go on is the SQL you've provided but from a brief look it does not appear that the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT() > 0` statements are required as the combination of the `INNER JOIN` condition in the sub-query and the use of `EXISTS` in the outer query does the same thing.

Does this have exactly the same functionality:

```
SELECT  chcr.chsid,
        CASE
        WHEN EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
          FROM   hdr_run chre
                 INNER JOIN
                 clmerr ce
                 ON (chre.clm_error_sid = ce.clm_error_sid)
          WHERE  chre.chsid    = chcr.chsid
          AND    chre.run_nmbr < chcr.last_run_nmbr
        )
        THEN 'Appended'
        ELSE 'Never Appended'
        END Run_Detail
FROM    clm_res chcr
        INNER JOIN
        clm_der chde
        ON ( chde.chsid = chcr.chsid );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45c28/1/0)

Also, repeated execution of the `CASE` statement is not a bad thing as the optimizer should not duplicate executions of the sub-query.